# Why is ssh agent forwarding not working?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx, forwarding

In my own computer, running MacOSX, I have this in ~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
Host b1
ForwardAgent yes
```

b1 is a virtual machine running Ubuntu 12.04. I ssh to it like this:

```
ssh pupeno@b1
```

and I get logged in without being asked for a password because I already copied my public key. Due to forwarding, I should be able to ssh to pupeno@b1 from b1 and it should work, without asking me for a password, but it doesn't. It asks me for a password.

What am I missing?

This is the verbose output of the second ssh:

```
pupeno@b1:~$ ssh -v pupeno@b1
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to b1 [127.0.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 35:c0:7f:24:43:06:df:a0:bc:a7:34:4b:da:ff:66:eb
debug1: Host 'b1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pupeno/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pupeno/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
pupeno@b1's password:
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It turns out my key was not in the agent, and this fixed it:

**OS X**:

```
ssh-add -K
```

**Linux/Unix**:

```
ssh-add -k
```

You can list loaded keys using:

```
ssh-add -l

ssh-add -L # for more detail
```

Comment: Note that `ssh-add -K` is specific to OS X.

Comment: Do you have to do this at every reboot?

Comment: You executed `ssh-add -k` in your own computer or in the server (b1)?

Comment: Not only is `ssh-add -K` specific to MacOS, as @RogerLipscombe points out, but it also has security implications that may or may not be desirable.  In particular, with `-K`, "When adding identities, each passphrase will also be stored in your keychain" -- meaning one would never again be asked for the key-specific passphrase, instead only needing (MacOS) keychain access. YMMV, but this is not what _I_ would want.  The `-k` option is not as problematic, but probably isn't necessary.  A simple `ssh-add` (perhaps with a `-t` time, too) would probably do, assuming an agent is running.

Comment: as of 2023, running `ssh-add -K` on MacOS 12 Monterey gives a warning. `WARNING: The -K and -A flags are deprecated and have been replaced by the --apple-use-keychain and --apple-load-keychain flags, respectively.` run `ssh-add --apple-load-keychain` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Another possible reason is connection sharing: one might already be logged in on the other host without agent forwarding and connection sharing enabled. The second login with `ssh -A` (or equivalently specified in the config file) via the shared connection will silently ignore the `-A` flag. Only after completely logging out or disabling connection sharing for second login, the agent forwarding will work.

Comment: YES!   Some may not remember that they have `ControlMaster` set in their config.  If master is active and you make a new connection with agent forwarding it will not work. Assuming you are a careful user who want the agent forward for a short period of time use `-ASnone` instead of the `-A` (or `ControlPath none` in config)

Answer (score 8):

1. Check if your `~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_dsa` `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa` files have the correct permissions which should be owned by your user and be chmoded 600.
2. Check that you have the correct public key on `pupeno/.ssh/authorized_keys` on b1, and check if `authorized_keys` has a line break at the end of the key.
3. Check if you have ssh-agent running, try to load keys via `ssh-add`
4. Try GSSAPI-based authentication and forwarding with `ssh -K`

Comment: The permission of the keys are fine and the key in authorized_keys is fine (otherwise I think I would have trouble connecting on the first place).

Comment: Did you have ssh-agent running? What happens when you do an ssh-add then ssh -A pupeno@b1 and then ssh pupeno@b1 ?

Comment: Why don't you update the answer to mention ssh-add -K and I'll accept yours instead of mine (since the information was posted almost simultaneously).

Comment: The remote .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh folder must also have correct permissions. Also a symlink to a file with correct permissions may not be accepted. This can fail silently in some OpenSSH versions.

Answer (score 8):

I had problem with sshd server rejecting agent forwarding request because of no space left in /tmp. This was because sshd needs to create socket in /tmp. Cleaning disk up resolved my issue.

ssh -v said back then:

```
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled: mkdtemp() failed: No space left on device
```

Comment: I had the same issue, only the permissions were wrong on /tmp. THANKS!!

Answer (score 7):

For me, it was simply that the host I was connecting to (**b1** in the original poster's example) was running it's own persistent `ssh-agent`.
There's no debug output I could see to explain what was happening, the host just silently uses it's existing `ssh-agent` and no forwarding occurs.
This makes sense to me *in retrospect* :p

The forwarding is like ssh port-forwarding: it's tunnelling, not client-server negotiation.

I *assumed* it was the latter - that having an `ssh-agent` running on the host would be necessary for agent forwarding, so I set it up at the beginning, but that was a mistake.

See the following examples:

First I ssh to host **ccam** (a raspberry pi) with no Agent Forwarding and confirm there's no agent socket or added keys:

[image: No agent forwarding]

Secondly I edit `.bashrc` to ensure ssh-agent is running on the host (**this was my mistake**). You can see when I reconnect using `-A` to enable Agent Forwarding, the agent socket exists, but the agent has no identities (I now realise that is because this is showing the local ssh-agent socket rather than a forwarded one):

[image: Added ssh-agent to host]

Finally, I remove the `ssh-agent` on the raspberry-pi host (not shown) and reconnect. You can see the key is finally available when inspecting using `ssh-add -L`:

[image: Successfully forwarding ssh key]

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't have the reputation on StackExchange to post the images inline, but it would be a better post if they were (help a fella out?)

Comment: There you go! :)

Comment: You're a scholar and a gentleperson - many thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you! I had made the same assumption about the agent and was making the host spawn and connect to an SSH agent for convenience. Now I'm making sure the user is not connected through SSH before starting the agent. Sometimes I feel like SSH couldn't be more confusing.

Answer (score 4):

For the benefit of other googlers who also arrived at this question:

Incorrect whitespace in a ~/.ssh/config file can also cause some head scratching.

I recently helped out one of my co-workers who had this:

```
# incorrect
host foobar ForwardAgent yes
```

instead of this:

```
# correct
host foobar
  ForwardAgent yes
```

I've also run into instances where missing indentation of the directives under the list of hosts made a difference to functionality, even though it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another cause: If the target host's fingerprint doesn't match with your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, SSH automatically disables Agent Forwarding.

The solution is:

```
$ ssh -A -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  my-target-host
```

Answer (score 2):

I had disabled agent forwarding for all hosts, thinking I could enable it for each specific host where I need it. Apparently that doesn't work.

```
Host *
  ForwardAgent no

Host myserver
  HostName myserver.example.nl
  ForwardAgent yes
```

The solution was to remove the `ForwardAgent no` from the `Host *` block.

Comment: That was the most helpful tip for me. I also thought that the specific host entry would override the global setting. But that doesn't seem to be the case. It would be handy to have things like ForwardAgent turned off by default and only turned on for some individual use cases. But obviously this cannot be done within one configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines to .ssh/config file

```
  Host **Server_Address**
     ForwardAgent yes
```

Add key to SSH Agent

```
 ssh-add -K
```

Connect to Remote Server

```
ssh -v **username**@**Server_Address**
```

Run connection test against GitHub

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Run ls remote test against targeted git repository

```
git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:**account**/**repo**.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Every SSH daemon must have:

`AllowAgentForwarding yes`

Comment: even if you specify ```ForwardAgent yes``` in your config?

Comment: `ForwardAgent` is a client option indeed you can find it in `man ssh_config` but not in `man sshd_config`

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to a machine running [byobu](https://www.byobu.org/)/tmux it seems that sometimes you need to create a new window on the destination machine (e.g. Ctrl-B + C) after you connect with `ssh -A` so that you can use your ssh agent for onward authentication.